# How do I use fetch with WireGuard in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, vpn, wireguard

I need to use a VPN in a few parts of my NodeJS server but only when fetching from one APIs. Everything else in my server should work as normal. I am using WireGuard, I could use OpenVPN but I prefer WireGuard as I get much slower speeds with OpenVPN. I am not sure if this is possible and how I do it.

I have done some research and ended up writing this below in NodeJS and it did not work. I am not that knowledgeable about networking, so I do not understand everything. What I did notice is that when I run the command "Get-NetIPInterface" in PowerShell with WireGuard connected with my VPN normally, I can see it there. But when I disconnect from WireGuard it disappears, and I am not sure if that has anything to do with it, but that's all the information I can think of that could be of help since I am a bit clueless.

```
import http from "http";
import axios from "axios";

const interfaceWg = "---";
const agent = new http.Agent({
  localAddress: interfaceWg,
});

const axiosWg = axios.create({
  httpAgent: agent,
});

const url = "---";

// Make an HTTP request using the axios instance with the WireGuard agent
axiosWg
  .get(url)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("Response:", response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
```

It ends up just doing a normal get request as far as I can tell, when I do a get request on websites that show me my IP, I get my IP and not the one from the VPN like I want.